# AutoComplete="Off"or autocomplete="none" or autocomplete="new-password" is not working

Tags: html, autocomplete

`AutoComplete="Off"` or `autocomplete="none"` or `autocomplete="new-password"` is not working in chrome and firefox browser. I tried many links from StackOverflow but nothing worked for me.

Comment: See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Security/Securing_your_site/Turning_off_form_autocompletion#preventing_autofilling_with_autocompletenew-password

Answer (score 1):

try this it worked in my case

```
<input type="password" name="password" id="password" autocomplete="false" readonly onfocus="this.removeAttribute('readonly')>
```